# How to add table of non-geo data to Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I have a parcels layer for a city, and every parcel has ID and I have a table in the database (not linked) contains transactions that happened on these parcels like (buying or renting) and some other data.
Every transaction has the ID of that parcel.

My question is how can I upload this table (transactions) to my Arcgis online map and link every transaction to the parcel using the parcel ID .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a [relationship class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/relationships/creating-a-simple-relationship-class.htm) between your parcels and the table in ArcMap file geodatabase.
2. Add your feature class with its related table into an ArcMap map document.
3. [Publish your map as a hosted feature service](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/publish-features.htm) in ArcGIS Online with Feature Access option enabled.

When identifying features in ArcGIS Online map viewer or WAB, you can see the related records in [pop-up](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-pop-ups.htm) or in WAB [Attribute Table widget](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-attribute-table.htm).

Comment: Hey , I did create relationship class and it works on the ArcMap but after I publish the map as service to my organization its not working anymore, the table is empty on ArcGis online ... any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Please post a new question with more specific details on what you have done, how, and what you see. Me and others could take a look!

Comment: here is a link to my teammate's question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219654/arcgis-online-wont-show-anything-after-clicking-show-related-records